# How to use loop for my multiplication/division calculator?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is what I have so far. Can't figure out how to use a loop so that I know where the user clicks and how to use the proper function.

```
import math
from graphics import *

def main():

#Create window to hold other objects
win = GraphWin("Calculator", 700, 400)
#Set color to blue
win.setBackground("azure")
#Set coordinate system
win.setCoords(0, 0, 4, 4)

#Display instructions for user
prompt = Text(Point(2, 3.75),
              "Enter two numbers and click an operand, or exit.")
prompt.draw(win)

#Setup calc boxes
o1 = Text(Point(0.65, 3), "Operand 1")
o1.draw(win)
o2 = Text(Point(2.65, 3), "Operand 2")
o2.draw(win)
tres = Text(Point(3.5, 3), "Result")
tres.draw(win)

#Draw entry box
e1 = Entry(Point(1, 3), 5)
e1.setText("0")
e1.setSize(10)
e1.setFill(color_rgb(200, 255, 255))
e1.draw(win)

e2 = Entry(Point(3, 3), 5)
e2.setText("0")
e2.setSize(10)
e2.setFill(color_rgb(200, 255, 255))
e2.draw(win)

resultrec = Entry(Point(3.8, 3), 5)
resultrec.setText("")
resultrec.setSize(10)
resultrec.setFill(color_rgb(200, 255, 255))
resultrec.draw(win)

#Operations
multrec = Rectangle(Point(.5, 2.3), Point(1.5, 1.75))
multrec.draw(win)
tmult = Text(Point(1, 2), "Multiply")
tmult.draw(win)

divrec = Rectangle(Point(2.5, 2.3), Point(3.5, 1.75))
divrec.draw(win)
tdiv = Text(Point(3, 2), "Divide")
tdiv.draw(win)

exitrec = Rectangle(Point(1.75, .75), Point(2.3, .2))
exitrec.draw(win)
texit = Text(Point(2, .5), "Exit")
texit.draw(win)

exit = False
while(not exit):
    win.getMouse()
    multrect == calc_mulity


main()
```

This is a basic calculator where the user inputs 2 numbers and either clicks multiply, divide, or exit. All the above is a working code, except bottom loop. I can't figure out what the loop needs in order to figure out where the user clicked.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask. Is this working code? What are you looking to do exactly?

Comment: @idjaw This is a basic calculator where the user inputs 2 numbers and either clicks multiply, divide, or exit. All the above is a working code, except bottom loop. I can't figure out what the loop needs in order to figure out where the user clicked. Thanks!

Comment: So this line: `while(not exit):` is where things are not working?

Comment: Where are you actually reading the entry to store it in `exit` to check if it is ever `True`?

Comment: what is this line supposed to do `multrect == calc_mulity`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the [graphics.py](https://mcsp.wartburg.edu/zelle/python/graphics/graphics/node1.html) module, then you need to modify the last few lines:

```
while(not exit):
    point = win.getMouse()
    # here you must handle the user input appropriately, 
    # detecting what has been pressed and act accordingly
    # ...
    multrect == calc_mulity
```

Note that while `graphics` is intended to be a beginner's package, doing a calculator this way is quite laborious. You should use a more modern method based on an event loop, such as the `Tkinter` module, which comes with the standard library. Tkinter is more advanced though, so you may want to build up your skills gradually before doing a graphic calculator. I suggest to start with a text based one (i.e. evaluate simple expressions).